# jquery display list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two or more unordered lists with the first list item in each visible and the others hidden.

When the first list itme is clicked it should show all the other li below and hide any other li's that are open in another ul.

I cant seem to get it to show correctly.

I cannot change the class names from the example I have as they are generated deep inside core code and used for other elements.

Thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/En7KV/4/

Comment: *it should should* what?

Comment: sorry, yes "should show"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul').on('click','.maincat',
           function(e){
               // prevents the default click action of the a element
               e.preventDefault();

               // finds the sibling elements, and shows them if hidden,
               // hides them if visible
               $(this).siblings().toggle();

               // finds the closest ul ancestor of the clicked element
               // finds the other ul siblings of that ancestor-ul
               // finds the '.maincat' class element's siblings that are visible
               // hides those visible elements
              $(this)
                 .closest('ul')
                 .siblings('ul')
                 .find('.maincat')
                 .siblings('li:visible')
                 .hide();
           });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/En7KV/6/).

---

**Edited** to add references (below) and this note:

Please be aware that, as of jQuery 1.7, the `live()` method is deprecated (and, as such, support may, or more likely *will* be dropped). For jQuery 1.7+ use the `on()` method (see the references, below) and prior to 1.7 the `delegate()` method is recommended in preference.

My reference for this note is the API documentation for `live()`, see references.

Please note

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Thanks, David, wouldn't have been able to do that. I have learnt something new.

Comment: Edited the answer to add references, and a note about using `on()` instead of `live()`.